# Bootstrap align button bottom of div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align this button in the center of the div and at the bottom.
The text should just fill up the div from the top. Thanks

```
  <div class="panel-body" style="float:left;margin-top:15px;width:40%;height:222px;background-color:#000000;" >
  yolof fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffffffffffff fffff
  <br>
  <a href="page.php" class="btn btn-primary" >Open Page</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4HYY/). I am not sure what exactly you want to happen.

```
<a href="page.php" class="btn btn-primary" style="width: 100%; position: relative; top: 120px;">Open Page</a>
```